# Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 Carousel formatting with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get twitter bootstrap carousel working (3.0+) with some formatting so I cycle through image on the right/text on the left- image on the left, then text on the right.

When rendered (rails 3.13) it seems as if the grid system is suspended-images are jammed on the left border here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jaytho/gvAMz/2/

but the example is lifted straight out of the bootstrap website:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5-offset-1">
                <img src="http://ndevilla.free.fr/lena/lena.jpg" alt="..."></img>
                <div class="carousel-caption">Caption</div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                     <h1>Some profound text here</h1>

                    <p>this is an image from my image processing past</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://perception.csl.illinois.edu/gpca/applications/baboon_small.jpg" alt="..."></img>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="..."></img>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
```

```
</div>
```

Is this by design?  (This is my first post)

Answer (score 1):

You have too many different div's and classes inside of your rows.

Here is an example that does what you are requesting using two .col-xs-6 inside of each .row or 'slide'. Using the example code and comments from Bootstrap's Carousel Examples - http://goo.gl/v2qY3J

Take a look - http://cdpn.io/wcpuf

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img alt="First Slide" src="http://placekitten.com/g/350/280">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>Temporary Title Text on the Right</h1>
        <p>Some paragraph copy for fun</p>
    </div>
</div><!-- end row -->
```

Comment: Yours works the same: jams the left hand image all the way to the left border and ignores any container grid formatting (the reason I have so many).  My workaround was to apply 'text-right' to any left-hand image. My expectation is that if I apply 'col-xs-offset-1', in your example, the image to skootch over.

Comment: hmm not envisioning what you are trying to accomplish. can you shoot over a photoshop of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Looks like my image formatting issue is due to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078649/twitter-bootstrap-styling-using-media-grid-class